# Saving audio files in mobile with expo Audio

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, audio

I want to save recorded audio messages of my user in his phone for that I need to access his phone to save the audio in any file from where later I can retrieve back but I have no idea how can I do that? A possible solution I get to see is to store in Firebase storage or AWS bucket and store the URL in the database but I want to store that audio files in the user phone.

```
async function startRecording() {
 try {
    console.log("Requesting permissions..");
    await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
    allowsRecordingIOS: true,
    playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
  });
  console.log("Starting recording..");
  const recording = new Audio.Recording();
  await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(
    Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY
  );
  await recording.startAsync();
  setRecording(recording);
  console.log("Recording started");
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Failed to start recording", err);
  }
 }


 async function stopRecording() {
   console.log("Stopping recording..");
   setRecording(undefined);
   await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
   const uri = recording.getURI();
   handleStoringFilesInPhone(uri)
   console.log("Recording stopped and stored at", uri);
   console.error("URI", uri);
}
```

**I want to store the URI getting back from expo audio in the user's phone how can I do that?**

Answer (score 1):

the file is saved in the phone by default. The uri you have is a local uri

Comment: if its saved by default, then what is the location of it?

Comment: you have the uri here => console.log("Recording stopped and stored at", uri);
you can store that somewhere and use it back anytime in the expo app.
you could use https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/async-storage/